# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered for Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, overflow, linear-regression

I am getting RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered for Numpy functions while doing the linear regression algorithm.  This is resolved with normalization but I don't want to normalize things. I tried the Dtype method but I do not know where to put it.

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  inner = np.power(((X * theta.T) - y), 2)  
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce
  return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  temp[0,j] = theta[0,j] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term))
```

Can you tell me what things I can change to avoid the errors.

```
def computeCost(X, y, theta):    
    inner = np.power(((X * theta.T) - y), 2)  
    return np.sum(inner) / (2 * len(X)) 

for j in range(parameters):

            term = np.multiply(error, X[:,j]) 
            temp[0,j] = theta[0,j] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term))
```

Added the data

```
150,100,0.73
159,200,1.39
170,350,2.03
175,400,1.45
179,500,1.82
180,180,1.32
189,159,0.83
199,110,0.53
199,400,1.95
199,230,1.27
235,120,0.49
239,340,1.03
239,360,1.24
249,145,0.55
249,400,1.3
```

Comment: any particular reason you don't want to normalize? what is the current dtype of X?

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: Added the data, third column is the y, 1st 2 are x's.  The reason I dont want to normalize is because I dont know how to predict things after normalization.  Do I normalize all future data before making a prediction.  How do I use the data points 300, 300 in the future to predict a y.  I do not have any dtype for the x's.  I hope that helps